# Bind the data of form multiple times

Tags: angularjs

I have a drop down, which shows number from 1 to 8. Selecting number 3 will display a div of form starting date, end date, starting time, end time 3 times.

How to bind these data in array to get it in Angular controller?

Answer (score 0):

In your form, you put ng-model for each of the form you want to bind the data.
For example,

```
<div>   
<input ng-model="date.startingDate" >
<input ng-model="date.endDate" > 
<input ng-model="date.startingTime" >  
<input ng-model="date.endTime" >
</div>
```

And in your controller, you declare date object in your scope so that it binds together. It will look something like this:

```
$scope.date = {}
$scope.date.startingDate;
$scope.date.endDate;
$scope.date.startingTime;
$scope.date.endTime;
```

Now the variables are bound to the scope and thus you can use its value dynamically.